PHP Mac OS X pg_connect on PostgreSQL 15 crashes only in Apache HTTPD
My PHP web app is crashing upon calling pg_connect when running on my Mac OS X machine ( it does not crash from a RHEL8 server ).
It's only happening when:

Connecting to a PostgreSQL 15 database server and
When running in Apache HTTPD (through CLI it works fine).

Meaning the script works when I run it from the CLI and it fully works (CLI and Apache HTTPD) when connecting to another PostgreSQL server running PostgreSQL 9.0.
On my local machine I'm running PHP 7.4.33
When I run the crashing script in Apache HTTPD, the error_log shows me this:
[Sat Nov 09 12:25:42.609490 2024] [core:notice] [pid 39732] AH00052: child pid 51781 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
The script is extremely simple:
<?php
$connString="host=<host> port=<port> user=<username> password=<password> dbname=<dbname> sslmode=disable";
$conn = pg_connect($connString);
echo "conn: [$conn]";
$result = pg_query($conn, "select 1");
echo "result: ". $result;
var_dump(pg_fetch_all($result));
?>

The output of phpinfo() is as follows (only including the relevant pgsql parts):
pgsql
PostgreSQL Support  enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   16.3
PostgreSQL(libpq)   PostgreSQL 16.3 on aarch64-apple-darwin23.4.0, compiled by Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4), 64-bit
Multibyte character support     enabled
SSL support     enabled
Active Persistent Links     0
Active Links    0 

The error logs don't give me any info besides the segmentation fault.  I have tried with both sslmode=disable and without to no avail.
I have tried this against 2 different sets of PostgreSQL v15.x servers (one a 15.8 and another on 15.9) and they both give the same results.
Are there any other troubleshooting I can do to pinpoint the exact problem or any additional info I can give ?

It is better to use the homebrew package https://brew.sh or if you are using an old mac you can use macports https://www.macports.org/install.php, here you will find it easier to solve problems especially because of the larger community.

Hello Ari, i did install apache httpd and php through homebrew.

please chek with brew services, try to restart http restart postgresql also, please use shivamathur php to install php@74-psql
